# SAP SSO Authentication as a rest service

Tags: java, rest, single-sign-on, netweaver

I have a legacy SAP Java application hosted on Neo platform which uses form-based SSO authentication. I want to consume this service from REST client like Postman which is not possible right now.

What options do I have?

Is it possible that I write a service on top of the current service and call the "original" service?

But again, how do I pass the SSO credentials to the "original" service?

Comment: How `form based SSO authentication` works?